# iptables on Linux router does not forward DHCP between two LANs

Tags: windows, iptables, routing, dhcp, port-forwarding

I have an internal network as follows:

- A Linux system that serves as router, using iptables, with two
  network cards
- A client machine
- A DHCP Server

The Router's eth1 is on the same LAN as the client.
The Router's eth2 is on the same LAN as the server.

Client ↔ [eth1] Router [eth2] ↔ DHCP Server

I've setup the Client to use DHCP, but I'm not able to get the correct iptable stanza to work (i.e., to forward the DHCP UDP packets between the client and server. The Client gives: `An error occurred while renewing interface Local Area Connection 2 : unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out.`).

This is the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` I have now, where the lines between the *#DHCP xxx* comments are what I'm trying for DHCP forwarding:

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth2 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o eth2 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
# DHCP start
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -p udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -p udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -p udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -p udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
# DHCP end
-A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

**Can you suggest changes that will enable the Client machine to get an IP address from the DHCP Server?**

Notes:

- IP forwarding on the router works, as I'm able to ping between Client
  and Server (and vice-versa).
- Router is CentOs, Client and Server are Windows.

Comment: Any reason why you are not just running dhcrelay?

Comment: I agree with @richardb. The only way to do what you're after is using a DHCP relay (isc-dhcp-relay in Ubuntu and Debian).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DHCP is a broadcast protocol you cannot forward (there is no destination IP on another network). What you need is an IP Helper showing to the DHCP Server (the router has to work as a DHCP Relay Agent, transforming the broadcast into a unicast).

Comment: Thank for pointing me in DHCP Relay direction. I've set it up and need to see if my client can be assigned an IP address from DHCP.
Thanks of course to richardb and @rsuarez also.